# What is the right way of merging?

Tags: git, merge, branch

Let's say I have 4 branches :

- develop : a branch where the code is validated by a peer and ready to be build
- local/1 : a branch where the code for the issue #1 is
- local/2 : a branch where the code for the issue #2 is
- local/3 : a branch where the code for the issue #3 is and it's needs the code from local/2 in order to work

Now, there is a rule in my firm :

- "Whenever an issue is treated, the branch that correspond to the issue should be merged to develop".
  And i don't want to wait until my peer validate my code to continue working.

What happens if the issue #2 is treated and branch local/2 is merged onto develop ? Is the branch local/3 lost because the initial commit's hash depends of branch local/2 ? How can i merge my branch local/3 without conflicts after the merge of develop and local/2 ?

Comment: `Is the branch local/3 lost because the initial commit's hash depends of branch local/2 ?` Branches don't depend on other branches. `How can i merge my branch local/3 without conflicts after the merge of develop and local/2 ?` Where is `local/3` branched off of?

Comment: local/3 is branched off of local/2 because local/3 needs local/2's features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Branch 3 is not lost unless you explicity delete it (git branch -d
   name).
2. If your files changed in the local3 are not changed in
   master, there will be no conflicts. But sometimes merge conflicts
   are not avoidable.
3. Intellij provides a very [graphic and good tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resolve-conflicts.html) to manage merge
   conflicts. Is freely available in community edition as well.